# How to install `coincbc` using Conda in Windows

Tags: python, windows, conda

I tried each of the following command lines in Anaconda Prompt:

1. `conda install -c conda-forge coincbc`
2. `conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 coincbc`
3. `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 coincbc`

and I get the following error in all cases:

> Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with
>   flexible solve.
>
> PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from
>   current channels:
>
> - coincbc
>
> Current channels:
>
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
> - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
> - http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi/win-64
> - http://conda.anaconda.org/gurobi/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
> - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
>
> To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package
>   you're looking for, navigate to
>
> https://anaconda.org
>
> and use the search bar at the top of the page.

What can be the possible reason for this error?

Answer (score 4):

This is what worked for me (Windows 10, Anaconda, working in an environment `my_env`):

- I downloaded the most recent binaries from [bintray](https://bintray.com/coin-or/download/Cbc) (for me, that was Cbc-master-win64-msvc16-md.zip)
- I unzipped the file
- I copied the contents of the bin directory (Cbc-master-win64-msvc16-md\bin)
- I pasted these .exe and .dll files in anaconda\envs\my_env\Library\bin

Comment: Hi MPa, thank you for your instructions. Unfortunately the link provided no longer works and in the new page this pop-up is shown:
```The download you’re looking for isn’t available any longer. Your download was hosted on JFrog Bintray, which has been deprecated. Please contact the project owner to get your downloads.```
Do you happen to know any other site that has these binaries? Thank you! :)

Comment: @charlieneutron Unfortunately not :/

Comment: If anybody is still interested, MPa's way worked for me. I got the .exe from https://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source/ as Bintray is deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

I found @MPa answer really helpful, although the link to download the most recent binaries is broken

So here it is an updated [link](https://www.coin-or.org/download/binary/Cbc/?C=M;O=D).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but there are no **win-64** builds for that package on Anaconda Cloud. Try following the suggestions on [the GitHub repository](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc#download) for alternative installation routes.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve use in anaconda prompt

```
pip install cbcpy
```

Answer (score 0):

The package name in conda-forge seems to be `coin-or-cbc`.

That said, conda-forge makes it available for Linux and macOS
but not for Windows. See:

- https://github.com/conda-forge/coin-or-cbc-feedstock/issues/3